# Parallel sparseMatrix cor(x,y) in R

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, doparallel

Asking same question as [Running cor() (or any variant) over a sparse matrix in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888287/running-cor-or-any-variant-over-a-sparse-matrix-in-r), but that solution only computes all-pairs, cor(x), is there a way to add the y argument to this computation, cor(x,y)?

Using a sparse cor(x,y) would allow an easy port to %dopar% to make it even faster by chunking across column sets like https://gist.github.com/LW6EGE/651feb519983b2fa1fadf52f4e44bc55.

Answer (score 1):

This is implemented in qlcMatrix::corSparse(x,y)